# PHPDoc multiple @param types inside @method

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I use PHPDoc to enhance PhpStorm hinting. Normally, a method would have a PHPDoc like this:

```
/**
 * @param array|callable $a
 * @param int $b
 * @return mixed
 */
public function x($a, $b) {
    // …
}
```

I need to describe the same inside a @method tag. PhpStorm (or PHPDoc) doesn't like the vertical bar. If I take it out with one of the types – everything looks good.

```
/**
 * @method mixed x(array|callable $a, int $b)
 */
class A {
    // …
}
```

First, is this a legal syntax for @method tag and the problem is with PhpStorm? If not, is there a way to describe arguments in full inside @method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not yet supported, just like specifying [**arrays of types**](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18194) using the bracket syntax.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22571

I'm not aware of any workaround for this, other than using `mixed` (which isn't really a workaround).

I'd suggest to comment and vote in the tracker.